# How to display variables from external JavaScript in HTML. Internet Explorer 7

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I realize this is a horribly newbie question, but Ive been trying to fix it for days trying different methods so I just wanted to ask what would you do.

I am attempting to create a web program to use at work, and I have this setup:

Windows 7
IE 7 - Cannot Upgrade.

The "website" is not a webhost, basicly I have a folder on my desktop with html/css/js files and I use IE to run the scripts, no host.

I want to keep a set of vars, mostly strings, in an external JS file and pull the JS into different HTML pages.  I want it to write on load of the document.. not on ready.  It does not have to be user dynamtic.

Also, When I make the js file, does it have to have a header.. like HTML has doctypes?

I really appreciate your help as I am trying to learn and will cont on my own from here.  My setup is much different than most, and im not sure which part was causing my problem so I finally broke down and posted.

Comment: How are you running IE7 on windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

When you write your JavaScript file it doesn't have to have any header or doctype. For example you can have a variables.js file that looks just like this:

```
var x = "abc";
var y = "def";
```

and have many HTML files that include variables.js like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
    <script src="variables.js"></script>
    <script>
      alert(x);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and your variables should be available there. Any script that is included after the reference to your variables.js should have access to everything that was included before without the need to listen to any events.

If you need to listen to the events then I suggest to use jQuery or some other JavaScript framework. An example for jQuery would be:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  alert(x);
});
```

A more advanced example of changing the DOM elements:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>Select variable:</p>
    <p>
      <a href="#" id="show-x">Show x</a>
      <a href="#" id="show-y">Show y</a>
    </p>
    <p>Value:</p>
    <p id="value"></p>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="variables.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#show-x').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#value').html(x);
      });
      $('#show-y').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#value').html(y);
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, if I change it up and go a button how to do I use javascript to write to an element.  Like, When a users clicks this button look in the external file and grab varaible x and include the string in <p id="inputlocation"> </p>

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a global variable, you can't display/print/access or whatever you call it because it has a local scope, defined in a function.

You can probably only use a debugger simply to debug it