# External javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, external

I have problem related to this post: [How to display variables from external JavaScript in HTML. Internet Explorer 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726128/how-to-display-variables-from-external-javascript-in-html-internet-explorer-7)

I want to load variables from external javascript files. I have two js files: `varible1.js` and `variable2.js`.

In `variable1.js` there is `var x1='hello'; // or somthing..`
In `variable2.js` there is `var x2='hello'; // or somthing..`

I have to use for loop to load files and access variables.

I want to load this js files with ajax:

```
for (i = 1; i < 2; i++) {         
    //ajax call then in success alert        
    alert(x+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to load with ajax when you can simply do it with

```
<script src="variable1.js">
<script src="variable1.js">
```

or if you want to load these variables with ajax you have to use

```
document.write(x1); //in variable1.js
document.write(x2); //in variable2.js
```

then the success() in ajax with return the values of x1 and x2.